# How to open multiple protected workbooks using xlrd, glob and pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

So I'm trying to open multiple excel workbooks and make changes on them, but they're protected and I don't know how to implement xlrd for it to work. Everything works with unprotected workbooks, but when I add a password to them, I get the error `XLRDError: Can't find workbook in OLE2 compound document` linked to the `data = pd.read_excel(f,header=2)` part.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import win32com.client
import glob
import pandas as pd
from xlrd import *

path = r'C:\...'
files = os.listdir(path)

dfs = []
for f in glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx"):
    **xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(f, False, True, None, 'fernanda')**
    data = pd.read_excel(f,header=2)
    dfs.append(data)

"""Columns we're going to to manipulate"""

date = "DATE OF CHANGE"
id = "ID"

df = pd.concat(dfs)
df[date] = pd.to_datetime(df[date], errors='coerce')
master = df.groupby(id).min()

for i in dfs:
    i[date] = i.join(master,rsuffix='_adj',on=id)[[date+"_adj"]]

r = zip(dfs,glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx"))
r_list = list(r)

for i in r_list:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(i[1])
    i[0].to_excel(writer,'sheet1', startrow=2)
    writer.save()
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: That seems to be an unsolved problem. This workaround I found needs another library called `xlwings` and an installed `Excel' (so is Windows only probably): https://davidhamann.de/2018/02/21/read-password-protected-excel-files-into-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried that first, but I got the same error :/

Comment: If you can code in VBA, I suggest just using pywin32 plus VBA then pandas

Comment: I'm trying that now, but how can I convert a win32com workbook into a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, just modify it for your loop

```
xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
#open password protected workbook, link on this command at the bottom
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(filename, None, None, None, "your password")
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
data = ws.Range("A1:D4")
#now data.value will return a tuple of tuples that you can put in a dataframe
values = data.value
#assuming the first row is the header
df = pd.DataFrame(values[1:],columns=values[0])
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open

Comment: I keep getting the error `com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)`

Comment: @FernandaF. try xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, True, None, password)

Comment: tried, same thing. I don't know if it's because I have more than 2k rows in each file